# Android native library references incorrect shared library

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I am building an Android native application that uses [OpenAL Soft for Android](https://github.com/AerialX/openal-soft-android). Everything builds nicely, resulting in two shared libraries in my libs folder: libdig.so (mine) and libopenal.so (the OpenAL library).

When I try to load libdig.so on the device (using `System.loadLibrary( "dig" );`), however, the link fails with the message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libopenal.so.1" needed by "libdig.so"; caused by library "libopenal.so.1" not found
```

Now in some sense the problem is obvious. dlopen is looking for a dependency named `libopenal.so.1`, but the file actually on the system (copied there by `ant install`) is `libopenal.so`: with no `.1`.

In other words, the `libopenal.so` library is called just that everywhere, except that somehow, internally, `libdig.so` references it as `libopenal.so.1`.

Also relevant: When building libopenal, the actual shared library name is `libopenal.so.1.13.0`, with two symlinks: `libopenal.so.1` and `libopenal.so`. But nowhere is the `.1` version referenced: not in Application.mk, or Android.mk, not in the output libs/, or anywhere else.

Android.mk links the libraries thus:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := openal
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../Fresh/lib/openal-soft-android-master/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libopenal.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(BASE_PATH)/Fresh/lib/openal-soft-android-master/include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

...

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += openal
```

Now, what is interesting is that if I literally delete the `libopenal.so.1` symlink from my system, `ndk-build` will fail, complaining:

```
No rule to make target `openal-soft-android-master/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopenal.so', needed by `obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopenal.so'.
```

This implies that internally, ndk-build *is* trying to reference the `.1` symlink, even though it's never named and the output file will be `libopenal.so`.

I am not familiar enough with UNIX or Android development to really understand the purpose of the `.1` symlink, so I don't know why there would be this secret reference to that file.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Or do you understand something deeper down about the compilation or management of shared libraries that would explain why libdig.so is referencing a (slightly) wrongly-named library, or how to change it?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a couple of years old, but I recently ran into the exact same problem while re-porting my game to Android.  This problem frustrated me, and I even tried Alex's link above, only to find I had the same problem. After spending days researching this problem, I came to the following conclusion based on a similar problem someone else had in a forum.  The .1 at the end is generally a sign of either using a library that was not built for your target platform (in this case, Android, obviously) or an incorrectly built library altogether.

If you want a quick fix to get around this (without statically compiling OpenAL-Soft into your app while forcing your entire project to be subject to the LGPL), you can simply download some prebuilt libraries from SFML's github page [here](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/tree/master/extlibs/libs-android/armeabi-v7a)... that's what I did anyway.  You don't have to replace the .a files if you don't need to.  Builds for arm, armv7, x86 and mips are in their respective folders.

Hope this helps either the OP or someone else in the future.

Comment: The dependency on ".so.1" comes from the linker flag **soname** used to build the dependency library (in this case, openAL). For many libraries, this can be tuned by a parameter to ./configure but static libs have no such problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way out would be to use the static library for OpenAL. You can find the prebuilt static libraries in the same [ZIP file](https://github.com/downloads/AerialX/openal-soft-android/openal-soft-android-251011.zip) as the shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

using openal-soft distrib or git 
edit openal-soft/build/CMakeFiles/openal.dir/link.txt
remove '-Wl,-soname,libopenal.so.1'
and rebuild the lib